# Tracking currency portfolio

Tags: finance

Google Finance only allows tracking a stock portfolio. Is there a service or a desktop program that allows tracking of different currencies with respect to a reference one, and get the current value of the lot?

I'm looking for two things:

1. (mandatory) the ability to input the amount I have for each currency, and get out the total sum I possess as of today considering the current rates.
2. (optional) the ability to see a graph of each currency's recent trends, similar to Google Finance, but in a more lightweight presentation.

Comment: do u want stack portfolio or currency ?

Comment: which operating system you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) is more of a bookkeeping system, but also supports portfolio management - can get stock & mutual fund reports automatically from the web, allows you to [control how you want currency conversion](http://svn.gnucash.org/docs/guide/currency_howto1.html) handled, and generated text & graphical [reports](http://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.0/C/gnucash-help/reports.html#report-types) in the [currency of your choice](http://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.0/C/gnucash-guide/chapter10.html).

GNUCash runs on GNU/Linux, BSD, Solaris, Mac OS X and Microsoft Windows.

[image: Multiple currency account scenario]

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives:

Gadgets for iGoogle: http://www.google.com/ig/directory?q=Currency+Exchange+Monitor

Current and Historical Rate Tables by XE: http://www.xe.com/ict/

A commercial solution: http://www.currencysystem.com

Comment: Nice, but not what I need. I'd like two things: 1, mandatory) be able to put the amount I have for each currency, and get out the total sum I possess as of today considering the current rates. 2, optional) being able to see a graph for the trend of each currency, similar to google finance, but in a more lightweight presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can track currencies with google finance, for example:

http://www.google.com/finance?q=USDEUR